# minikube curl: (6) Could not resolve host: service-name

Tags: kubernetes, devops, minikube

I have a ruby on rails deployment and I want to use it in the frontend deployment so I created a service exposing port 3000 called "flicron-backend-service"

here is the description of the service

```
kubectl describe svc flicron-backend-service                      
Name:              flicron-backend-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            io.kompose.service=flicron-backend-service
Annotations:       kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
                   kompose.version: 1.28.0 (c4137012e)
Selector:          io.kompose.service=flicron-backend
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.107.112.244
IPs:               10.107.112.244
Port:              3000  3000/TCP
TargetPort:        3000/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.144:3000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

I am trying to use the service name but it does not get resolved
I have tried from inside minikube to curl the backend-service-name did not work

```
curl flicron-backend-service:3000
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: flicron-backend-service

curl flicron-backend-service.default.svc.cluster.local:3000
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: flicron-backend-service.default.svc.cluster.local
```

but if I used the ip it works fine

```
curl 10.107.112.244:3000
# some HTML
```

Here is my DNS configuration

```
kubectl describe cm coredns -n kube-system
Name:         coredns
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
Corefile:
----
.:53 {
    log
    errors
    health {
       lameduck 5s
    }
    ready
    kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
       pods insecure
       fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
       ttl 30
    }
    prometheus :9153
    hosts {
       192.168.49.1 host.minikube.internal
       fallthrough
    }
    forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
       max_concurrent 1000
    }
    cache 30
    loop
    reload
    loadbalance
}


BinaryData
====

Events:  <none>
```

FrontEnd Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: flicron-frontend-service
  name: flicron-frontend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: flicron-frontend
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000
      nodePort: 32123
```

backend service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.28.0 (c4137012e)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: flicron-backend-service
  name: flicron-backend-service
spec:
  # clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - name: "3000"
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: flicron-backend # this maps this service to that deployment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried from inside minikube to curl the backend-service-name did not work

If you explicitly meant that you've:

- connected to your minikube instance (i.e. `minikube ssh`)
- `curl` the service name directly from `minikube` instance.

Then it should **not work**.

It will work from a Pod/container that is targeting internal Kubernetes DNS resolution.

---

Let me explain:

DNS resolution within Kubernetes environment is handled by `coredns` residing in `kube-system` namespace. It is a containerized service that is hosted inside of Kubernetes. Information on how to connect to it is injected to Pods via Kubelet.

You can see it by:

- `kubectl run -it basic-pod --image=nginx -- /bin/bash`
- `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

```bash
nameserver 10.96.0.10 # <-- SERVICE KUBE-DNS IN KUBE-SYSTEM (CLUSTER-IP)
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

Minikube itself does not have the core-dns configured in `/etc/hosts`.

Try to contact your `Service` with an actual `Pod`:

- `kubectl run -it basic-pod --image=nginx -- /bin/bash`
- `apt update && apt install dnsutils -y` - `nginx` image used for simplicity
- `nslookup nginx` - there is a `Service` named `nginx` in my `minikube`

```yaml
root@basic-pod:/# nslookup nginx
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.109.51.22
```

I encourage you to take a look on following documentation:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: DNS Pod Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)*

Comment: ok so if I understand correctly, curl from the minikue won't work because it does not have a kublet that can resolve the service name but if I tried curl from inside the pod it should work right?
I tried from the frontend pod and the backend pod and the curl worked successfully. 
`- kubectl exec -it frontend-pod -- /bin/bash
- curl flicron-backend-service:3000/
- # some HTML
`  
the question now is why in the front end (from the browser) this HTTP request fails flicron-backend-service:3000/graphql ?

Comment: Kubelet is a software installed on every ‘Node’ in the cluster. Minikube is having it also. It is not configuring the host os ‘/etc/resolv.conf’. Do you maybe have a minimal reproducible example of your setup? What I mean by that is the resource yamls and images.

Comment: I have added the yaml files of the services (sorry for the late reply)

Comment: From YAML perspective it looks okay. Maybe it’s related to how the application is configured inside of the container?

Comment: 1. I am using the default images for react app and ruby on rails (the most used ones), and I the .en lv file I change the backend url to the service name of the backend

Comment: 2. I gave up using the service name, and I used ingress file and made both the backend and the frontend exposed to outside of the cluster and finally worked, is this solution correct?

Comment: Your frontend to backend traffic should be handled by internal services like clusterip. Im not sure why it is not working. Maybe its specific to the application. Id reckon someone else can shed some light on it. Exposing by ingress is okay only to services that are customer facing (not dbs etc)

Comment: Yes, I found out that the backend should be exposed as well, because of an integration with other systems. So it worked out in the end, Thanks for your help Mr Dawid Kruk